# How do I collect nested hash values into an array in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Say I have the following hash.

```
my_hash = {
  'array1' => %w[
    value1
    value2
  ],
  'array2' => %w[
    value3
    value4
  ]
}
```

How do I make an array that looks like

```
my_array = %w[value1 value2 value3 valuu4]
```

Comment: `my_hash.values.flatten`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_array = my_hash.values.flatten
=> ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Flatten Hash Values

Use [Hash#values](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values) to collect the values from your Hash, and then use [Array#flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-flatten) to turn the result into a single Array rather than one containing nested arrays. For example:

```
my_hash.values.flatten
#=> ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
```