# How do I get the key for a certain value in a nested hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby

This is a follow question to [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633689/how-do-i-collect-nested-hash-values-into-an-array-in-ruby/33633814#33633814) I posted earlier.

Say I have the following hash.

```
my_hash = {
  'array1' => %w[
    value1
    value2
  ],
  'array2' => %w[
    value3
    value4
  ]
}
```

What is the fastest or simplest way to get the key for a certain value in one of the arrays. For example, I want to get the key for value2, and get array1, or get the key for value3 and get array2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest you can go with the existing data structure is to scan all arrays in the Hash:

```
key, _ = my_hash.find{|k, v| v.include? "value3" }
```

If this lookup is an operation that is performed many times and you need to go faster than this, you may consider a data structure that allows for faster lookups, like one of the following:

- convert the inner arrays into [Sets](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)
- construct a reverse lookup Hash, where the values (`value1`, `value2`, etc.) would point to the corresponding key in the initial hash (if all the values are unique).

Comment: I would think both  alternatives you mention would be slower, as they require the arrays to be traversed to create a set or hash (followed be a single lookup), whereas `include?` terminates a traverse when a match occurs.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You are right. I saw the word "faster" in the question and immediately thought of a scenario that required good lookup performance. I have edited my answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_hash.detect { |_, v| v.include? 'value2' }.first
```

Please note, that if there are many keys, having `value2` in the values array, this approach will return the very first one.

To receive *all* keys, one might use:

```
my_hash.select { |_, v| v.include? 'value2' }.to_h.keys
```

or:

```
my_hash.map { |k, v| k if v.include?('value2') }.compact
```